# WIKI replacement solution for SharePoint?

Tags: moss, wss, wiki, enterprise

I'm trying to research a replacement for the pathetic WIKI that comes with WSS (only wiki code it has is to create url links).

I have looked at a few but most 'replacements' I see are MOSS only? (or so it just states MOSS for requirements).

Has anyone faced this situation? What did you end up using? I would like something that I can have all in one location (not different apps, hence WSS). With LDAP / AD Integration like WSS.

Thanks appreciate any input. I would like to see ~ $3k solutions tho (nothing super expensive, hence why we don't run MOSS).

**EDIT:**

Anyone else have any suggestions?

**EDIT2:**

Actually since I haven't had much feedback (thanks to those that have).  I installed **mediawiki** under IIS with PHP enabled, and enabled the IIS AD hack for authentication.  IIS ends up prompting for authentication (user/pass) if you use a non IE browser, then it sets the `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]` variable, and grabs some AD info (groups etc).  Works rather well, only issues is the UGLY urls so far. But its fully working.  Seems like a good setup. Other than having to rely on MYSQL (my company strives to be mainly SQL Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) after the MOSS Wiki definitely didn't meet our needs.

While it's still a Wiki and thus has some limits on its formatting etc., it's quite good, offer Office imports, Office viewers, PDF export functionality, and a whole slew of other features.

Comment: So I'm assuming you are running MOSS then? I was curious if it works with just plain WSS?

Comment: Confluence doesn't require anything in terms of MOSS - it's standalone. For us it was just the best replacement for MOSS wiki - it's really quite powerful, feature-rich, enterprise-grade, and supported by a professional company standing behind it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you checkout mindtouch. It's got a lot of tricks, is free, and has a great community.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, as of Atlassian Confluence v4.x, 2011,  they no longer support wiki-markup.

They (basically) only support an in-effective  WYSIWYG , GUI editor.

So now, Confluence is "just as bad" a choice, as Microsoft Sharepoint,  if you want to use Wiki Markup (quick !).

By way of reference, browse this long customer insurrection, on the Atlassian website,
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+4+Editor+-+Customer+Feedback

Answer (score 0):

[screwturn.eu](http://screwturn.eu) is your friend. There are multiple ways to rig up AD support. A couple of lines of code is quicker than the hours of *configuring* WSS